# What is the alternative of if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-style

I want to shorten the if conditions. Is there any alternative other than switch case?

```
 public void check(String name){

        String parentFolder = "";
        

        if(name.matches("birds"))
            parentFolder = birdPFUuid;
        if (name.matches("dogs"))
            parentFolder = dogPFUuid;
        if (name.matches("cats"))
            parentFolder = catPFUuid;
        if (name.matches("vehicles"))
            parentFolder = vehiclesPFUuid;


}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you don't need `matches` and `equals` suffices, you could also use a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: switch statement ... java allows switch on string values. Checkout tutorial : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map data structure to map the parent folder UUID to the dataset name.

```
Map<String, String> uuidMap = new HashMap<>();
uuidMap.put("birds", birdPFUuid);
uuidMap.put("dogs", dogPFUuid);
uuidMap.put("cats", catPFUuid);
uuidMap.put("vehicles", vehiclesPFUuid);

public void check(String name){
    String parentFolder = uuidMap.get(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To shorten multiple if-else statements you can use inline if:

```
((condition == value)?'expr1':'expr2')
```

`expr1` executes when condition is true, else `expr2` executes.

```
String parentFolder = "";
parentFolder = (((name.matches("birds"))?"birdPFUuid":
                 (name.matches("dogs"))?"dogsFUuid":  // if "dogs" then set parent folder to "dogsFUid" else check code in line below
                 (name.matches("cats"))?"catsFUuid":
                 (name.matches("vehicles"))?"vehiclesFUuid":""
));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).